# Regex to pull set of numbers from a string

Tags: regex

This is my string:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:1:"i";s:5:"19807";s:1:"c";s:19:"7025462932180014917";s:1:"a";
d:88.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875;s:2:"ba";
d:88.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875;}}
```

Im just looking to pull out the portion that starts with `702546` and ends before that double quote after the `7`. The number may be a varied length but will always start with `702546` and always end at the quote mark.

So my final selection would be `7025462932180014917`.

Comment: Is it for this specific string only or more general?

Comment: What rules govern the selection of that particular portion over the other numeric parts of the string? Do you have more examples of inputs and required outputs?

Comment: Why that particular number instead of others?  Also this looks like a PHP object serialization format.  Why not just unserialize into an object and get the property you are looking for directly?

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=")(702546\d+)(?=")`

if youe regex engine doesn't support lookbehind use this regex `"(702546\d+)"` match will be in group 1

Answer (score 0):

The basic regex is `702546[^"]*` to match any string like that, but you probably want to use a programming language of some sort to actually pull those out.

```
vnix$ grep -o '702546[^"]*' file
```

Or in a scripting language, something like this;

```
perl -nle 'print $1 while m/(702546[^"]*)/g' file
```

Your problem description leads me to believe that this is not actually what you should be doing, though.  [What problem are you really trying to solve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

This could vary a bit depending on the technology/language you are using, but basically you can use something like this

```
(?<=")702546\d+(?=")
```

The first `(?<=")` may be overkill if there is no risk of other numbers in your string starting with 702546.

Breaking this down:

```
(?<=") // a zero-width assertion (lookbehind), so we will only match if preceded by double-quotes
 702546 // literal match
 \d+    // one or more additional digits
 (?=")  // another zero-width assertion (lookahead), so we will only match if followed by double-quotes
```

Basically, a zero-width assertion just means that the value must be there in order for a match to succeed, but the value does not become part of the match. We use them here because we want to be sure that the value is enclosed in quotes, without making the quotes part of our match.